# What is the difference between a homeomorphism and an isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I've been taking online lectures on topology. I'm a beginner in this field. I came across the terms homeomorphism and isomorphism, and I don't understand them. I want to know the definitions of each with maybe some examples and the significance of studying them. Thank you

Comment: Did you look at the corresponding wikipedia pages?

Comment: See Wikipedia for [Homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) and [Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism). It has many examples.

Comment: I would like to get some perspectives from  people in this site which really helps me to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism is a category theoretic concept, it is an invertible structure preserving "map". As an example, a bijection is an isomorphism between sets, and a homeomorphism is an isomorphism between topoogical spaces, which is a continuous bijective map with its inverse also being continuous.